# Finding the middle letter and make it uppercase.. am stuck and the end .. :(

Tags: java

Here am finding the middle letter of each element of the array and making it upper case and merge it so that it'll give me a result like e:g-  {bOy, inDia, apPle}

Following is the code am trying till now.

```
public class FindMiddle {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();

        al.add("boy india apple");

        String str[] = al.toArray(new String[al.size()]);
        String newar[];
        String delimiter = " ";

        newar = str[0].split(delimiter);

        for (int i = 0; i < newar.length; i++) {
            char[] c = newar[i].toCharArray();
            for (int j = 0; j < c.length; j++) {
                if (j == c.length / 2) {
                    c[j] = Character.toUpperCase(c[c.length / 2]);
                    System.out.println(c[j]);
                }
                newar[i] += c[j];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It's only giving me O D P.

I want them merged with the original elements like bOy inDia apPle.

Comment: al.add("boy india apple");

Comment: do you want ODP or bOyiDiaapPle

Comment: it should be like  {bOy, inDia, apPle}

Comment: You have a single place where you print stuff. And the stuff printed is the char that you just made uppercase. What you want it to print every letter, after it has been uppercased or left untouched.

Comment: yes.. JB ..but i'm not able to know how to get that uppercased lettter merge with the original word.

Comment: @user3499450 i posted my answer

Answer (score 2):

that's because you print only the middle char (the println is inside the if statement)

```
 if (j == c.length / 2) {
        c[j] = Character.toUpperCase(c[c.length / 2]);
        System.out.println(c[j]);
 }
```

I would suggest using [StringBuilder.setCharAt](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/stringbuilder_setcharat.htm)

```
 for (int i = 0; i < newar.length; i++) {
            StringBuilder updateString = new StringBuilder(newar[i]);
            int middleIndex = newar[i].length /2;
            updateString.setCharAt(middleIndex, Character.toUpperCase(newar[i].charAt(middleIndex));
            System.out.println(updateString); 
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

you could use the  `charAt` function of the `String` object and `replace` function
using the full `String.length` is not accurate when you will be accessing the middle index of the `String` since index are `length - 1` (because it starts with 0) so you need to deduct 1 from the length and then divide it by half.

```
for(int i=0;i<newar.length;i++){
            int index = (newar[i].length()-1)/2;
            newar[i] = newar[i].replace(newar[i].charAt(index), Character.toUpperCase(newar[i].charAt(index)));
            System.out.println(newar[i]);
        }
```

output:

```
bOy
inDia
aPPle
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this** :

```
         for (int i = 0; i < newar.length; i++) {

        char[] c = newar[i].toCharArray();
        for (int j = 0; j < c.length; j++) {

            if (j == c.length / 2) {
                c[j] = Character.toUpperCase(c[c.length / 2]);
                //System.out.print(c[j]); <--- you keep getting O D P because you 
                                               print them here
            }
            // newar[i] += c[j]; <-- here you just concat changed elements to newar
            System.out.print(c[j]); <--- print the value of array none middle and middle one
        }
        if (i != newar.length-1) { <-- avoid printing , for last item
            System.out.print(",");
        }
    }
```

**output**:

```
bOy,inDia,apPle
```

**My explanations are as comment inside the code.**

**Note**: when you are in a for loop, you are checking whether you ecnounter the middle character. if you encountered, you will make it uppercase other wise nothing is changed, and each character is printed out on the console.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class Test
{
   public static void main(String[] args) {

      ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();

      al.add("boy india apple");

      String str[] = al.toArray(new String[al.size()]);
      String newar[];
      String delimiter = " ";

      newar = str[0].split(delimiter);

      for (int i = 0; i < newar.length; i++) {

         char[] c = newar[i].toCharArray();
         for (int j = 0; j < c.length; j++) {

            if (j == c.length / 2) {
               c[j] = Character.toUpperCase(c[c.length / 2]);
               // System.out.println(c[j]);
               // (1)    
            }

            System.out.print(c[j]);
            // (2)               

            newar[i] += c[j];

         }
         System.out.println();
         // (3)
      }
   }
}
```

(1) - I got rid of this because it would only print out the uppercase letter. You had set the middle characters in all 3 words to uppercase, but, you need to print out the whole word, not just one letter.

(2) - You do, however, want to print out the whole word, which is what this line is doing. Instead of doing println, it only does print. Reason is because we are taking advantage of that for loop that is going through each character in the specific word to be able to print out each letter after we are done checking if it's the middle letter.

(3) - We have this line here because we want to be able to separate between words. I am not sure how you want these words separated so change this as you feel it's necessary, I just separated them so you could see.

Comment: Good, now I'm not sure the output is how you wanted it, do you need help with that too? Or is the output format good?

Comment: no no..that i 'll manage..my problem was i was printing in a wrong block of code.. and trying to append it original and breaking my head.. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
String temp = ""; //define temp string as "" (don't assign null)
for (int j = 0; j < c.length; j++) {
    ...
    //newar[i] += c[j];  //don't append to existing String in array
    temp += c[j];
    newar[i] = temp;
}

//after replacement is done
//now can print replaced string in array by looping
for (String string : newar) {
        System.out.println(string);
}
```

Comment: appending null before printing the desired result..like nullinDia

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of things wrong with your code, so here is a simplified rewrite:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "boy india apple";

    String[] split = s.split( " " );
    String[] toReturn = new String[split.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < split.length;i++)
    {
        String word = split[i];
        char[] chars = word.toCharArray();
        chars[chars.length/2] = Character.toUpperCase( chars[chars.length/2] );
        toReturn[i] = String.valueOf( chars );
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString( toReturn ));
}
```

In order to correct your code you can start by removing the useless ArrayList and moving the System.out outside of the for loop. There are some other issues like you are appending the new result to the original so newar after this runs will look like {boybOy, indiainDia, appleapPle}.

EDIT:

For teaching purposes, here is your code modified so that it will work; however inefficient.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();

    al.add("boy india apple");

    String str[] = al.toArray(new String[al.size()]);
    String newar[];
    String delimiter = " ";

    newar = str[0].split(delimiter);

    System.out.print("{");
    for (int i = 0; i < newar.length; i++) {
        char[] c = newar[i].toCharArray();
        for (int j = 0; j < c.length; j++) {
            if (j == c.length / 2) {
                c[j] = Character.toUpperCase(c[c.length / 2]);
            }
            System.out.print(c[j]);
        }
        newar[i] = String.valueOf(c);
        if (i < newar.length - 1)
            System.out.print(",");
    }
    System.out.println("}");
}
```